# How can I subscribe to a BehaviorSubject from another service in a service?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cli

I have 2 services: A and B
I create a BehaviorSubject in A and want to subscribe to it in B.

```
export class ServiceA{
   someAttribute: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
   otherAttribute: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
   constructor(){
       otherAttribute = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false); 
   }
}
...
export class ServiceB{
   constructor(){
       someAttribute.subscribe(newValue =>{...}); 
       otherAttribute.subscribe(newValue =>{...}); 
   }
}
```

**The Problem:**

Service B only run the subscription once. Meaning after the constructor is done, the subscription is too.

**The Question:**

How can I subscribe to a BehaviorSubject from another service in a service?

**Other Info**
I'm working with Angular CLI and am a bit new to BehaviorSubjects. 
I wanted to split the responsibilities of 2 Services, but one of them is dependant to the other and has to listen to changes of some Attributes.

I also cannot make a circular dependency, meaning that service is dependant on B (B->A) and B on A (A->B). I only want B to be dependant on A, so that A is responsible to provide the Information and B listens to them.

Comment: where are you pushing new changes to that subject 
there is only one default value false

Comment: Doesnt matter where. In a component, Service A or B or another Service.

Answer (score 0):

From your psuedo-code it looks like you are already subscribing to the BehaviorSubject from Service A in Service B. If you want to emit new values you will need to call `.next`

```
someBehaviorSubject.next(someValue)
```

---

Also you may want to consider exposing the Subject as an Observable via the `asObservable` method. Exposing a Subject directly as you are doing is potentially dangerous as it allows consumers to directly access the Subject API - i.e. they can call `.next` and emit values. In your case this would mean that Service B could trigger Service A to emit. That may be what you want - in which case that's OK - but if not its safer not to give consumers this option. Something like:

```
export class ServiceA{
    constructor() {
        this.foo = this._foo.asObservable();
    }

    private readonly _foo = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    public readonly foo: Observable<boolean>;
}
...
export class ServiceB{
   constructor(private readonly _serviceA: ServiceA){
       this._serviceA.foo.subscribe(value => {
           ...
       }); 
   }
}
```